# JFrog Artifactory OSS displaying port in "Set me up"

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have recently setup JFrog Artifactory OSS and I have it running behind a nginx reverse proxy with a Lets Encrypt SSL certificate.

I can access the site fine (without inputting the port etc). However; when I click the "Set me up" button on a repository; it has the port in the `<url>` field. It's displaying like this;
`https://sub.domain.net:443/artifactory/maven-releases/`

I have set Artifactory's base URL to https://sub.domain.net/

I have included my configuration for nginx.

```
server {
      
    server_name www.sub.domain.net sub.domain.net;
 
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }
    rewrite ^/$ /ui/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/ui$ /ui/ redirect;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout  2400s;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass          http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8082;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout non_idempotent;
        proxy_next_upstream_tries    1;
        proxy_set_header    X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 
        location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
            proxy_pass    http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8081;
        }
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.net/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


}
server {
    if ($host = www.sub.domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = sub.domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80 ;
      
    server_name www.sub.domain.net sub.domain.net;
    return 404;

}
```

Comment: I should also mention; I can access `https://sub.domain.net/artifactory/maven-releases/` just fine. It's just display incorrectly inside of Artifactory.

Comment: There's an issue on jFrog's Jira about this: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14084.

It's still unanswered. If you can, please vote on it.